# Reference standard Qlik Sense table object in button extension javascript

Tags: qliksense

I want to build an extension that takes a table of data from the Qlik Sense UI and submits it to the REST API of another application.

I could build my own table extension and add the button to that table, but then I would need to replicate much of what the standard table object does in my extension code. I think a simpler approach would be to allow the user to 'link' the button extension to a standard table object in the extension configuration. However then when the extension button is clicked we would need to load data into json from an object other than the extension itself. An extension can easily reference its own data in the paint() function, but in this case I wold need to reference data in a different object and not have to configure dims & measures for the extension at all.

Is this possible, and are there any good code examples (eg. a similar extension on Qlik Branch) that I could reference to learn how to do it?